# Tefilla b’Tzibur during Bayis HaRishon?

Tags: tefilla, beis-hamikdash, synagogue, yeshiva-school, tefillah-betzibbur

During the תקופתו של בית הראשון and even before, did forms of Tefilla and Limud b’Tzibur/ Basei Knessios exist among people?

During my years in Yeshiva, this topic was gently discussed. I remember hearing that during שנת שמיטה everyone would go to Batei midroshim and learn the whole year, and same with on Shabbat during a regular year. Other than that I have not heard of how a regular day would go for בני תורה בתקופת הבית הראשון

Comment: I will be watching this question too. If you don't get an answer here, if you find good yeshivish or chassidish sources for this, please come back and answer your own question for us to see because I'd love to learn more about this too.

Comment: apparently where they would daven and learn would be two different places

Comment: I have heard theorised that the 'minyan' was a mechanism created by chazal to keep yidden together once the Beis Mikdash was no longer a central focul point. If true, it follows that this would've started during first golus.

Answer (score -1):

Each tribe had their own nusach hatefillah (liturgy of prayer), and their was a thirteenth (the arizals one now) which is an all inclusive “master key” which we use nowadays as we don’t know which tribe we are from now.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. See particularly the importance of sourcing your answers. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Im not sure how accurate that is... Ashkenaz ,sefaradi, temani etc nusachot were not designed based off of which shevet the users were apart of. Currently, Leviim and Yisraelim dont have different nusachot. Plus much of our tefillos were written and instituted by Chazal (eg Amidah, Birkos hashachar, tachanun, etc) sometime during Ezra hasofers time.

Comment: All the splits may have come after the churban, with each community adding what they wanted around the same basic nusach, and I have no clue what the other 12 nuschaos looked like. A possible answer to your point about the leviim would be the same as why they still say all the nesiim in Nissan.

Comment: Regardless does not answer the question